# Ruby on Rails SLES11 Install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, installation, rvm

Has anyone had a successful attempt at a Ruby on Rails install for SLES11? I've attempted to install a copy of Ruby2.0 and Rails4.0 using RVM but had all sorts of difficulties with dependencies and it makes me wonder if RVM is truly compatible with the SLES11 version of Linux.

I'm running SLES11 SP2 with all the available repositories(to my knowledge) but have been largely unsuccessful at several variations of an install usually due to package requirements and dependency issues. It's not as simple as adding a package though when each package has dependencies of its own or requires things like an architecture change. Or upgrading a package when it's dependencies cannot be upgraded.

An install on SLES11 doesn't seem to be very well documented which is what brings me here. Looking for any ideas or routes I can pursue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found very similar report here: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1991

Should be fixed after:

```
rvm get head
```

If it's not comment in the mentioned ticket with details.